# javascript works in debugger but not in run mode

Tags: javascript

i am using google.api to validate address and then make an ajax call to insert into database if the address is valid. but the google code is executed after if ((lati === undefined) && (longi=== undefined))where its setting the address invalid. Can some please suggest why its not executing google.map before it checks the lati and longi for undefined.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(), lati,longi;
    $("#editDistributor").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         height: 550,
         width: 550,
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
             "save": function() { 


                 if ($( "#distAddress" ).val()) {tempAddress = $( "#distAddress" ).val();}
                 if($( "#distCity" ).val()) tempAddress = tempAddress + $( "#distCity" ).val();
                 if($( "#distState" ).val()) tempAddress = tempAddress + $( "#distState" ).val();
                 if($("#distZip").val()) tempAddress = tempAddress + $("#distZip").val();
                    geocoder.geocode({'address': tempAddress }, function(results, status) {
                          if(status) {
                           google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK:
                            lati=results[0].geometry.location.k;
                             longi=results[0].geometry.location.D;


                          }
                        });

                if ((lati === undefined) && (longi=== undefined)){
                alert ( "Invalid Address");   
                }else{

                 var dialog = $(this);
                var mapContent = new Object();


                 if($( "#distCompany" ).val() != undefined){
                    mapContent.name=$( "#distCompany" ).val();

                 }else{
                    alert("Please enter company Name");
                 }

                $.ajax({  

                      type: "POST",  
                      url: window.location.origin+"/"+window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]+"/map/create", 
                      data: JSON.stringify(mapContent),  
                       dataType: "html",  
                       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 

                      success: function(response){                     
                            alert("yes");
                      },  
                      error: function(){  
                          alert("Failure");   
                      }  
                 });  
                   }
              },

             close: function() {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
             }
         }
     });
```

thanks

Comment: If you're adding the google maps script to the page using async or defer the script dependency won't have loaded by the time your `document.ready` callback gets called, but this is just a guess without seeing the markup you're using.

Comment: sorry but i did not get you

Comment: zzzzBov is right, you have to put the second ajax post inside the callback of geocode. Async call are executed after the main flow of your code.
EDIT: Callback results are invoked after the main flow. 
EDIT 2: the document.ready is not the problem, you get the lati and longi variables after the request to geocode is completed, meanwhile your code keeps going and you evaluate variables before they are setted

Comment: @G-Host, Without seeing the rest of the code, or the error message, and knowing that the google maps script might be called after document ready, `new google.maps.Geocoder()` could be failing. As it is this question doesn't include enough information to properly debug the issue, so [I'm voting to close it as off-topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)